# Apache - Getting Alerts on Traffic/Spiders Exceeding a Threshold

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, files, logging, alerts

What tools can I use to monitor my Apache Log files and create alerts based on traffic. I need to:

- Get an alert when a spider that is outside of a defined list exceeds a set number of requests in any given day.
- Get an alert when traffic from a network outside of a defined list exceeds a set number of requests in any give week.

I can view this data in AWStats and Google Analytics but I want to set up automated alerts for this. I could hand roll some scripts but I thought their might be an existing solution. We are running on Linux/Apache/MySQL and an open source solution would be a plus.

Answer (score 1):

Since you parse the logs with **AWStats**, you could use the information it collects in its *database*, which is a *plain text* file and is pretty easy to parse.

Look for the section:

```
BEGIN_ROBOT ..
[...]
END_ROBOT
```

The amount of bandwidth each spider has consumed is aggregated in the **third column**. I bet you could easily write a small script that retrieves the information you need and sends you an alert if the bandwidth consumption exceeds the limits you have set.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you're looking for, but if you want a serious log management application, have a look at [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/). It will do what you want and a lot more.